# C++: using templates to collapse repetitive code with different types and functions

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a library that allows Lua to read and write arbitrary bytes in a block of memory as different types and byte orders. I've used C++ templates to avoid repetition to some degree, but I haven't been able to avoid it entirely:

```
/* Read one or more sequential values from the blob and push to the Lua stack
 * using lua_pushinteger().
 * Lua: the Lua state to push to.
 * offset: The byte offset to read from.
 * count: The number of values to read.
 * This method is called from Blob::read() which is called from Lua methods.
 * For offsets outside the valid range, it returns nil.
 */
template <typename T>
lua_Integer Blob::readi(lua_State *Lua, lua_Integer offset, lua_Integer count) {
    if(offset < 0) offset += this->size;
    else offset--; //make 0-based

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if(offset >= 0 && offset < this->size) {
            T value = *(&this->data[offset + this->pageOffset]);
            lua_pushinteger(Lua, value);
            offset += sizeof(T);
        }
        else lua_pushnil(Lua);
    }
    return count;
}

/* Same as readi but uses lua_pushnumber
 * even with templates we end up duplicating logic :|
 */
template <typename T>
lua_Integer Blob::readf(lua_State *Lua, lua_Integer offset, lua_Integer count) {
    if(offset < 0) offset += this->size;
    else offset--; //make 0-based

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if(offset >= 0 && offset < this->size) {
            T value = *(&this->data[offset + this->pageOffset]);
            lua_pushnumber(Lua, value);
            offset += sizeof(T);
        }
        else lua_pushnil(Lua);
    }
    return count;
}
```

When we want to read a `float` or `double` value, we have to use `lua_pushnumber(lua_State *Lua, lua_Number num)` instead of `lua_pushinteger(lua_State *Lua, lua_Integer num)`. (Usually `lua_Integer` is a typedef of some integral type such as `int32_t`, and `lua_Number` is a typedef of `double`.) So I don't know how I can avoid duplicating this function using templates, since `lua_pushinteger` and `lua_pushnumber` accept different types.

Additionally, I want to add support for specifying the byte order (using functions from `endian.h`): you can specify that the values being read are assumed to be in big endian order, little endian, or native (whichever the host machine is). Again, I don't know how to achieve this with templates, since the byte order functions deal with different types.

Comment: write overriden function helpers (`lua_push_anything`), if that fails use traits or tag dispatching.

Comment: "since the byte order functions deal with different types". Show a non-template version.

Comment: I ended up doing what @Yakk suggested. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void lua_push_anything( lua_State* s, lua_Integer i ) {
  lua_push_integer( s, i );
}
void lua_push_anything( lua_State* s, lua_Number i ) {
  lua_push_number( s, i );
}
void lua_push_anything( lua_State* s, bool b ) {
  lua_push_boolean( s, b ); // actually takes an `int`.
}
void lua_push_anything( lua_State* s, std::string s ) {
  lua_pushlstring( lua_State* s, s.c_str(), s.size() );
}
```

this solves the type problem -- you have a single override that dispatches to the correct `extern "C"` `lua_*` function.

You can deal with endianness in similar ways if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a traits class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class ReadTraits
{
//Has a typedef-ed callable type called ReadFunc.
};
```

You would specialize this for the types `T` you want to be able to read in. Now, your `read` function would look like this :

```
template <typename T>
lua_Integer Blob::read(lua_State *Lua, lua_Integer offset, lua_Integer count) {
    if(offset < 0) offset += this->size;
    else offset--; //make 0-based

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if(offset >= 0 && offset < this->size) {
            T value = *(&this->data[offset + this->pageOffset]);
            using ReadData = typename ReadTraits<T>::ReadFunc;
            ReadData(Lua, value);
            offset += sizeof(T);
        }
        else lua_pushnil(Lua);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You need to rewrite `using ReadData = typename T::ReadFunc; ReadData(Lua, value);`

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this use of `using` or `typename`. What is that statement doing?

Comment: [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), in this case, is no different from a `typedef`. `typename` is needed in template definitions to tell the compiler that what follows after the `::` is indeed a type and not a class member.

Comment: @pradhan if `T` is `int` it won't work: usually you do `traits<T>::whatever` not `T::whatever`

Comment: @Yakk Ugh. I am blind :) Thanks!

Comment: @Pradhan and use `ReadData{}(Lua, value)` if it is a callable type, or `auto ReadData = &ReadTraits<T>::ReadFunc` if it is a `static` method.  You rarely want the constructor of your callable type to be how you call it.  :)